# Eigenspaces of convolution and irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

In [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/254a-notes-3-haar-measure-and-the-peter-weyl-theorem/) Terry Tao talks about Haar measure and the Peter-Weyl theorem. Convolution is defined as
$$ (f*g)(x)=\int f(y)g(y^{-1}x)dy,$$
where $dy$ is the Haar measure, and $g(y^{-1}x)=[yg](x)$ is a translation of $g$ by $y$.

After his Exercise 12, Tao states that the eigenspace of convolution,
$$V_{g,\lambda}=\{f \;| \; f*g=\lambda f\}$$
is invariant under translations (this is easy to prove using invariance of the measure).

So the space of $L^2$ functions on the group can be decomposed in terms of these eigenspaces of convolution $V_{g,\lambda}$. On the other hand, it can also be decomposed in terms of irreducible representations (Peter-Weyl theorem).

My question is what is the relation between eigenspaces of convolution and irreducible representations.

Comment: As you say, the eigenspaces are invariant under translations, so they are direct sums of the irreducibles. They won't be irreducible in general (e.g. $g$ could be constant or even zero). But you can hope that they're irreducible if $g$ is sufficiently generic. This happens at least if $G$ is finite, for example, which is a nice exercise.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I will do the exercise for finite groups. But for compact groups, is there no theory saying for example what conditions on $g$ provide irreps? Or when different $g$ will give rise to equivalent spaces? Etc?

Comment: I think (based on the case of finite groups) that it will also be true that "generic" values of $g$ produce irreducibles, but proving it seems more annoying in this case. Convolution with $g$ acts by some scalar $\lambda$ on each irreducible (by Schur's lemma) and you need to pick $g$ sufficiently generically so that these scalars are distinct for distinct irreducibles. Maybe the Stone-Weierstrass theorem will help here.